# Cast exception in foreach loop

Tags: java, exception, classcastexception

I have a function that is throwing me a Class Cast Exception. This is the function

```
public boolean checkIfBrandExists(String brandName) {
        boolean brandExists = false;
        
        for (Brand brand : this.brandList)   
        {
            if (brand.getName().equals(brandName)) {
                brandExists = true;
            }
        }

        return brandExists;
    }
```

As the Oracle doc says *"Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance"*. I need help to see how this relates to my function.
Here is the full stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class classes.Dealership cannot be cast to class classes.Brand (classes.Dealership and classes.Brand are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at Main.checkIfBrandExists(Main.java:480)
        at Main.registerCarOrTruck(Main.java:133)
        at Main.registerVehicleInDealership(Main.java:363)
        at Main.registerMenu(Main.java:80)
        at Main.execute(Main.java:54)
        at Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

And here is the Dealership and Brand ArrayList

```
private ArrayList<Dealership> dealershipList = new ArrayList<Dealership>();
private ArrayList<Brand> brandList = new ArrayList<Brand>();
```

Comment: Can you share the complete stack trace

Comment: Could you please share Dealership and Brand classes?

Comment: @RajeshSamson Sure, I'll edit that

Answer (score 1):

Your **this.brandList** is an arraylist of **Dealership** and **not of Brand**.

Since **Brand** and **Dealership** are not hierarchically related, you are getting class cast exception.

Comment: How are the two classes (dealership and brand ) related ? Are they parent child?

Comment: They are two separate classes, no relation with each other.

Comment: Then of course you will get class cast exception bro. I think u didn't understand the point . Suppose you have a Person type and a Non-living thing type. You are casting a list of persons to a list of non living things. How will it happen? Both are two entirely different types having different characteristics

Comment: `brandList` is an arrayList of Brand objects. I edited the post with the declaration of the arrays.

Comment: After changing that, are you still getting the same error?